# Print Array on Laravel html table

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have some data that returns to me as a laravel array and I want to print it out in a table in a view, but I can't access that data

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    0 => array:3 [▼
      0 => "MS3939"
      1 => "20G1"
      2 => "20DC"
    ]
    1 => array:3 [▼
      0 => "MRK940"
      1 => "20R1"
      2 => "20RF"
    ]
  ]
]
```

this is my view code with the table

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
            <tr class="text-center">
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>ISO</th>
                <th>Type</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="filter-table">
            @foreach($datos as $dato)
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">{{$loop->iteration}}</th>
                    <td>{{$dato['0']}}</td>
                    <td>{{$dato['1']}}</td>
                    <td>{{$dato['2']}}</td>
@endforeach
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: `$dato[0][0]` and see what you get just for testing

Comment: If you've got nested arrays, you'll need nested `@foreach()` loops.

Comment: Thanks Akhtar It has worked to perfection, i need to read more about arrays..

Comment: Only one problem I've realized is that my foreach has become useless

Comment: No it's not useless, you can check the answer below, for more accurate way.

Comment: Note that your `@endforeach` should come after the `</tr>`.

Answer (score 0):

> If your `$datos` is a collection then do one thing.

```
$datos = $datos->flatten(1); //it will reduce one level of your array
```

> If your `$datos` is not a collection and it just an array then convert it to collection

```
$datos = collect($datos); //then
$datos = $datos->flatten(1);
```

> Then in view you are already running a loop, so you will be able to access data like...

```
<td>{{ $dato[0] }}</td>
<td>{{ $dato[1] }}</td>
<td>{{ $dato[2] }}</td>
```